# Cannot view variables in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Currently, I am using RStudio Version 0.99.442 with R3.2.0.

First, I imported data as `input` variable.

```
     NAME          NROW NCOL  MB
[1,] input      643,166   71 251
```

When I use `View(input)` to visualize my imported data, it just gave me the blank page.

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Can you try with the `?head` or `str` i.e. `str(input)`

Comment: Did you get any error or warning messages? The information you show about `input` looks strange. What happens if you try `head(as.data.frame(input))`? Can you also tell us more about your system?

Comment: @akrun @Roland I did not get any error message. Also, my 'input' is `data.table` containing 643166 rows with 71 columns. If I use `head`, I can see my data on the console panel.  However, I would like to visualize `input` in the view tab.  Is it because my data is large ?

Comment: The file is quite large. The reason might simply be insufficient RAM size. On a linux computer, try to type `top` in a terminal  and see if and how much Swap  is used. Detailed information on the amount of used and available memory can be obtained with `watch -n 5 free -m` (ubuntu linux).

Comment: Maybe encoding issues? I had that problem once. Try `View(sapply(input, function(x) enc2native(x)))`.

Comment: To check if it's a memory issue, you could also try to load only a part of the file and see if that works. This could be done, e.g., with the `read_csv()` command from the `readr` package: `input_first_thousand <- read_csv('mydata.dat', n_max=1000)`